# Make only one attribute editable in a webmap

Tags: arcgis-online, editing

Can someone tell me (spoon feed me) how to make only one attribute editable in ESRI online. Everything I have read and followed makes all the attributes editable.

I really need the public user to enter a date in the contractor start date attribute field, it would be best if they were not allowed to delete anything.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by editing the feature template in agol.
You do not outline what type of data you are editing.

you simply set it in the attribute settings. Right click on the layer> choose configure popup> shoose configure attrubutes...
[image: attribute settings]

Here are 5 links to help.
The first shows how to edit ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZetHXZcKFlQ)).
The second shows how to [manage the feature templates (AGOL Help)](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-feature-templates.htm).
If you are using enterprise geodatabase data and want to accomplish this I think you will have to disable editing for attribute fields at either the user level or the database level (depending on your security model).
The third link is to [editing features (AGOL help)](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/edit-features.htm).
The fourth is to [using url parameters (AGOL Help)](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/use-url-parameters.htm).
The fifth is to [esri training online (free seminars)](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseid=2563)
Now you can't say your esri knowledge is kindergarden. Go forth and spread the word.

Comment: @Ismael shows an excellent video on youtube. which shows using collector. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cW8odNeo6qM perhaps using the webappbuilder would allow you to make those changes in the service.